# Discover JPA primary key generation strategy at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Given the abbreviated JPA entity below, how can I discover what `GenerationType` the persistence provider chooses at runtime?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
}
```

When the `GeneratedValue.strategy` is not explicitly specified as in the example, it defaults to `AUTO`, and the [docs for `GenerationType.AUTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO) state this:

> Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database...

I want to see what strategy it actually picks at runtime.

Comment: enable the hibernate and jpa logs to the trace level, you can see what strategy it chose. It purely depends on the DB and JPA.

Comment: @AshraffAliWahab Why don't you post this as the answer? It's annoying to check out questions that are already answered. Thank you

Comment: @Simon it was a suggestion, not a complete answer thats why it was not posted.

Answer (score 0):

I would start using some reflective code like:

```
// setup code, it's just my code for this test...
Book b = new Book();
PersistenceProvider pp = new HibernatePersistenceProvider();
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<>();
BookJpaController bc = new BookJpaController( pp.createEntityManagerFactory( "myPP", m ) );
bc.create( b );

// reflective code to introspect the Entity and the PersistenceProvider
for ( Field f : b.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ) {
    if ( f.isAnnotationPresent( GeneratedValue.class ) ) {
        GeneratedValue gv = f.getAnnotation( GeneratedValue.class );
        System.out.println( gv.generator() );
        System.out.println( gv.strategy() );
        System.out.println( gv );
    }
}

for ( Field f : pp.getClass().getDeclaredFields() ) {
    try {
        f.setAccessible( true );
        System.out.println( f.getName() + " " + f.get( pp ) );
    } catch ( IllegalAccessException exc ) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```